# Update Revit custom properties by web API

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit, autodesk-bim360

It is possible to update and save a custom text attribute in a Revit project hosted on BIM360 ?
Our customer's advisor say it is possible, but after taking a look to the Forge API I do not see any reliable way to do it.
I'm wrong or I've missed something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess they are referring out new API, [Design Automation for Revit V3](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/), the new V3 API is still in Beta, but it has the ability to do the following task related to Revit file, including modify your Revit model:

- Create custom Revit family content
- Automate model creation
- Explore and analyze model data
- Extract and produce automated reports
- **Modify existing models to maintain company standards**
- Automatically create documentation

Also please check [Learn Forge about Modify Model](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels) as the sample on detail steps of implementation.

Comment: Hi @Zhong Wu, how about update in 2024 ? I'm tried check but may be it still not available ?

Comment: Hi ChuongHo, you can achieve this by Design Automation Revit, that's the current way.